# parse $(find ...) from python?

Tags: python, roslaunch, rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

how can I make use of the ROS API to parse roslaunch macros like `$(find <package>)`?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304563/parse-$(find-...)-from-python?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2018-10-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not well documented as I believe it's not really intended to be reused outside of `roslaunch`, but you do this by essentially calling `substitution_args.py::resolve_args(..)` ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/ef54759bf847ec53ac387a63dbefc556241fcf41/tools/roslaunch/src/roslaunch/substitution_args.py#L349-L393)).

An example can be seen in `xacro` [here](https://github.com/ros/xacro/blob/0ae956da439bde5dc3fe19d9abc06c618a5ef6e9/src/xacro/__init__.py#L181-L193).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2018-10-01**:
Exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!